# MyBatis : is it possible to set typeAlias in xml mapper?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

The [DTD file](http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd) has such element.

> <!ELEMENT typeAlias EMPTY>
>  <!ATTLIST typeAlias 
> alias CDATA #REQUIRED
>   type CDATA #REQUIRED
>   >

However according to DTD I can't understand what is its parent element. I tried to use this way:

```
<typeAlias alias="..." type="..." />
<mapper namespace="....">
</mapper>
```

and this way:

```
<mapper namespace="....">
  <typeAlias alias="..." type="..." />
</mapper>
```

but I get errors. So the question - is it possible to use aliases in mapper and if yes will they be linked only to current mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You cannot, the allowed elements are as below in mapper elements(cache-ref, cache, resultMap, parameterMap, sql, insert, update, delete, select)

```
<!ELEMENT mapper (cache-ref | cache | resultMap* | parameterMap* | sql* | insert* | update* | delete* | select* )+>
```

You can define the typealias in mybatis-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<typeAliases>
        <package name="com.kp.domain" />
        <!-- or as below -->
        <typeAlias alias="..." type="..." />
</typeAliases>
```